# Excel numers automatically formatted with Php currency

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am using a macro to do my daily tasks on excel. Recently I bought a new laptop  with excel 2007 in it and I noticed all numbers in a cell are automatically having a Php currency in them. I can remove them manually but it will add Php to any new records I put it. This was not happening on my previous computer with Excel. I wonder what settings I'm missing here? I just don't want excel to automatically format numbers into currency, especially Php currency.

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Control panel | Clocks Language and Region | Region and Language | additional Setings | Currency Tab`

And change the settings there. See screenshot below.

[image]